# Printing a multi-dimensional map in c++

Tags: c++, vector, maps

I'm having trouble printing a multi-dimensional map. I initialize it by

```
map<string, map<string, vector<double>>> mapData;
void Graph::addToGraph(string start, string next, double cos, double mile)
{
//see if the map contains the starting city string, add if not found
if (mapData.find(start) == mapData.end())
{
    mapData[start][start].push_back(invalid);
    mapData[start][start].push_back(invalid);
}

//see if the map contains the next city string, add if not found
if (mapData.find(next) == mapData.end())
{
    mapData[next][next].push_back(invalid);
    mapData[next][next].push_back(invalid);
}

mapData[start][next].push_back(cos);
mapData[start][next].push_back(mile);
double check = mapData[start][next][0];//test case
}
```

As far as I can tell it seems to me the map has been created correctly. I used a third dimension so I can store the mileage and the price. This will be used in a shortest path algorithm. I want to print each city, as well as all the connecting flights to the city with their mileage and price example, SFA SLC $700 59miles. Is this even possible, and if not how would I change it?

To give a better idea of why I'm using a map, the requirements of the project is that I read in from a file all the information, create a graph from that file, then let the user enter in the abbreviation of the city they want to start. Maps allowed me to specify a spot in an array with a string which was useful for this. But I'm not sure it will work with this algorithm.

Comment: You have easy access by which city the flights are from.  So you seem to be asking how to iterate through the transpose of your irregular data.  If you create a separate list of the "to" cities, then the access as if transposed is simple (if a bit inefficient).  If you wanted more efficiency you would have an entirely different data structure.

Comment: off topic: If you are programming for speed, do some tests to make sure the lack of good locality isn't going to kill your performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways:

```
for(auto& kv : map)
{
    std::cout << kv.first << std::endl;
    std::cout << kv.second.first << std::endl;

    for(double d : kv.second.second
    {
    //..
    }
//..
}
```

If you're doing other things with the data while you're looping over it you can create a vector of keys and `push_back()` `kv.first` within the loop, and then create another loop that iterates over the keys. I'm not certain that this is the fastest way but it certainly isn't too slow.

```
std::vector<std::string> keys;

for(auto& kv : map)
{
    keys.push_back(kv.first);
}

for(auto s : keys)
{
    for(double d : map[s])
    {
    //..
    }
}
```

Comment: `kv.third` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I've gotten to the point where I have been able to copy the second elements to a new vector, however I cannot seem to access anything in the second dimension of the map.

Comment: So, for a user to access the vector of doubles, they'll need two strings and an index: `my_map.at(string_1).at(string_2).at(index)`. You could also effectively make it a map of a custom type: `std::map<std::string, Data>` Where `Data` is a struct containing price, distance, or whatever other information you need and the string is the abbreviated name of the location. This way you can type `my_map[place].field` to access your data. So, for example: `my_map[place].price` or `my_map[place].distance`

Comment: This was most helpful in solving my problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
{
for (auto kv : mapData)
{
    for (auto kvv : kv.second)
    {
        if (kvv.second != invalid)
        {
            cout << kv.first << "<-->" << kvv.first;
            cout << " costs $" << kvv.second << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << distance(mapData.begin(), mapData.find("SLC"));
}
}
```

This is the function that I used to print my map. Thanks to Lucas for pointing me in the right direction